# Jenkins throttled builds creates multiple customworkspaces

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have configured to run build job with a max 1 concurrent build per node, and uses a customworkspace setting in the node agent config. However, over a while, we found multiple workspaces being created in the jenkins workspace directory.

```bash
$ ls
bazel-workspace
bazel-workspace@2
bazel-workspace@tmp
bazel-workspace@2@tmp
```

Is there some other knobs I can play with to make sure only a single workspace is used all the time?

Global config:

[image: throttle config]

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'bazel-worker'
      customWorkspace 'bazel-workspace'
    }
  }
  options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: !isMainline())
    throttleJobProperty(
        categories: ['bazel-build'],
        throttleEnabled: true,
        throttleOption: 'category'
    )
  }
}
```

Effective config for the pipeline:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't cause a problem in your execution, you can use the `ws` command and define the same workspace for every execution.